# How to calculate the confidence intervals for prediction in Regression? and also how to plot it in python

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

[image]

Fig 7.1, An Introduction To Statistical Learning

---

I am currently studying a book named Introduction to Statistical Learning with applications in R, and also converting the solutions to python language.
I am not able to get how to get the confidence intervals and plot them as shown in the above image(dashed lines).
I have plotted the line. Here's my code for that -
(I am using polynomial regression with predictiors - 'age' and response - 'wage',degree is 4)

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(4)
X = poly.fit_transform(data['age'].to_frame())
y = data['wage']
# X.shape

model = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
print(model.summary())

# So, what we want here is not only the final line, but also the standart error related to the line
# TO find that we need to calcualte the predictions for some values of age
test_ages = np.linspace(data['age'].min(),data['age'].max(),100)

X_test = poly.transform(test_ages.reshape(-1,1))
pred = model.predict(X_test)

plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
plt.scatter(data['age'],data['wage'],facecolors='none', edgecolors='darkgray')
plt.plot(test_ages,pred)
```

Here data is WAGE data which is available in R.
This is the resulting graph i get -

[image: This is what i was able to plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used bootstraping to calculate the confidence intervals, for this i have used a self customed module -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

class Bootstrap_ci:


    def boot(self,X_data,y_data,R,test_data,model):
        predictions = []
        for i in tqdm(range(R)):
            predictions.append(self.alpha(X_data,y_data,self.get_indices(X_data,200),test_data,model))
           
        return np.percentile(predictions,2.5,axis = 0),np.percentile(predictions,97.5,axis = 0)

    def alpha(self,X_data,y_data,index,test_data,model):
        X = X_data.loc[index]
        y = y_data.loc[index]
        
        lr = model
        lr.fit(pd.DataFrame(X),y)
        
        return lr.predict(pd.DataFrame(test_data))


    def get_indices(self,data,num_samples):
        return  np.random.choice(data.index, num_samples, replace=True)
```

The above module can be used as -

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(4)
X = poly.fit_transform(data['age'].to_frame())
y = data['wage']

X_test = np.linspace(min(data['age']),max(data['age']),100)
X_test_poly = poly.transform(X_test.reshape(-1,1))

from bootstrap import Bootstrap_ci

bootstrap = Bootstrap_ci()

li,ui = bootstrap.boot(pd.DataFrame(X),y,1000,X_test_poly,LinearRegression())
```

This will give us the lower confidence interval, and upper confidence interval.
To plot the graph -

```
plt.scatter(data['age'],data['wage'],facecolors='none', edgecolors='darkgray')
plt.plot(X_test,pred,label = 'Fitted Line')
plt.plot(X_test,ui,linestyle = 'dashed',color = 'r',label = 'Confidence Intervals')
plt.plot(X_test,li,linestyle = 'dashed',color = 'r')
```

The resultant graph is

[image]

Comment: very elegant solution!! 
Can you tell me what `def get_indices(self,data,num_samples):
        return  np.random.choice(data.index, num_samples, replace=True)` does?

Comment: It is used to get random indices. Data here is the data matrix, and num_samples is the number of indices that we want.

Answer (score 2):

Following code results in the 95% confidence interval

```
from scipy import stats

confidence = 0.95
squared_errors = (<<predicted values>> - <<true y_test values>>) ** 2
np.sqrt(stats.t.interval(confidence, len(squared_errors) - 1,
                         loc=squared_errors.mean(),
                         scale=stats.sem(squared_errors)))
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what does the returned value refer to here. Its returning a list of two items. What i am looking for is confidence interval for each predicted point. 
And how can that help me to get the graph that is mentioned in the first line of the questions. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I reworked the answer above using sklearn and a little easier to read (at least for me)

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()

# Some data
t = [[2004. , 2.4 ],[2005. , 2.09],[2006. , 2.03],[2007. , 1.7 ],[2008. , 1.56],[2009. , 1.88],[2010. , 1.61],[2011. , 2.14],[2012. , 1.57],[2013. , 1.78],[2014. , 1.69],[2016. , 1.64],[2017. , 1.33],[2018. , 1.38],[2019. , 1.42]]

t = pd.DataFrame( t , columns = ['year','value'] )

all_preds = []
# Bootstrap 500 times
for i in range(500):
    resampled = t.sample( replace=True, n=t.shape[0] ) # resample with replacement

    X = resampled['year'].values.reshape(-1,1)
    y = resampled['value'].values.reshape(-1,1)

    # Create model from resampled data
    model.fit(X,y)
    preds = model.predict( t['year'].values.reshape(-1,1) )
    preds = preds.reshape(1,-1)[0]
    # New predictions from resampled model
    all_preds.append( preds )

# Create dataframe of all predictions
all_preds = pd.DataFrame( all_preds ).T
all_preds.index = t['year'].values

# Calculate 95% confidence intervals for each year

def quantile(x,ci):
    return np.quantile( x , ci )

cis = all_preds.stack().reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1).rename( columns = { 0 : 'value' } ).groupby('level_0').agg( {'value': lambda x: [quantile(x,0.025) , quantile(x,0.975)] } )
# extract values
cis['high'] = cis['value'].apply( lambda x: x[1] )
cis['low'] = cis['value'].apply( lambda x: x[0] )

# Linear Regression to get predictions
model.fit( t['year'].values.reshape(-1,1) , t['value'].values.reshape(-1,1) )
preds = model.predict( t['year'].values.reshape(-1,1) )

# Plot
plt.plot( t['year'] , preds , color = color_dict['WQ blue dark']['hex'] , zorder=3 ) # 1. fit line
plt.fill_between( cis.index , cis['high'] , cis['low'] , facecolor = 'b', ec='none' , alpha=0.25 , zorder=2 ) # 2. confidence interval
```

[image: ci for lin reg]